# Should I use an online broker to buy travel insurance or Should I buy from the insurance company website?

Tags: usa, health-insurance, students, insurance

I will be travelling to United States to join a graduate program. I need to buy travel insurance for three weeks as I will be an early arrival student. I am thinking of buying Atlas Travel Insurance (HCC Medical Insurance Company). I would like to know if it is a good idea to buy travel insurance from an online broker like insubuy.com ? or should I buy the insurance from the insurance company's website directly ? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using each of these methods ?

Also, any information on the reliability of these online brokers like insubuy.com would be really appreciated.

Thank you